# Can we use Ember.js to build a static website?

Tags: web, ember.js

Can we use Ember.js to build a static website? We are going to store the website in AWS S3.

Kind regards

Comment: Not fully sure what you mean by "static website". The output of an Ember build is always a bundle of static HTML, JavaScript and CSS. Maybe together with some media like images, video etc. If you are referring to a JAMStack approach, have a look at Prember as pointed out in the answer by kiwiupover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes building a static site is how the emberjs.com website it build.

[Prember](https://github.com/ef4/prember) is the tool to build static sites with ember.

Comment: there is also empress-blog if you're looking at a blog-style static site https://github.com/empress/empress-blog

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes! Ember is a fantastic technology to build static sites in  as @kiwiupover mentioned [Prember](https://github.com/ef4/prember) is the main way to turn an Ember app into a "static site", and if you already have your website built as an Ember App it is very straightforward to add Prember and deploy it on a static site hosting (like AWS S3 or Netlify). If you want the simplest possible way to get started I would recommend deploying to Netlify.

[The Ember Website](https://emberjs.com) is a great example of a site that is built using Ember and gets great Lighthouse scores because it's also a static site. You can see the code in the [public github repo](https://github.com/ember-learn/ember-website)

All that is if you want to build something from scratch, but if you're looking for a super quick way to build a static blog then you could check out [empress-blog](https://github.com/empress/empress-blog) and you can get a blog up and running in less than 5 minutes if you follow the "super quick start" in the readme on empress-blog.

I have a bunch of other recommendations for building static sites with Ember but you can reach out to me on the Ember Discord (you can find a link on the [Community Page](https://emberjs.com/community/))